# What are typings and @types in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Can anyone help me to understand What are typings and @types in angular2?

How to define typings and how to use @types in angular2 with webpack?

Comment: is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175393/2545680)? don't forget you can accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typings are just [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) grouped together. Each declaration file defines symbols (interfaces, values, classes etc) available during compilation. This is required for type checking and intellisense. When you write the following:

```
export declare class AComponent { }
```

you're saying that there is class `AComponent` and so the compiler won't complain when you use it:

```
const o = new AComponent();
```

`@types` is just a namespaced [npm repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) where many typings (declaration files) are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript language, as a super-set of JavaScript, uses [type declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) to provide the desired type checking during compilation.

The [`@types`](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) name is just a scoping prefix name that helps to group all type definitions available at NPM.

Check the Angular "Typescript configuration" documentation for more details:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html